# Sequence of loading navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

My question is regarding the Breadth-first-like entity retrieval provided by EF.
In my EF code-first model, I have a tree-like hierarchy, e.g. a bill consisting of product instances and some surcharges.

```
public class Bill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BillSurcharge> Surcharges { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSurcharge> Surcharges { get; set; }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

I observed that in case of the above entities, the query

```
context.Bills.Include("Products").Include("Products.Surcharges").Include("Surcharges")
```

results in the following sequence of entity retrieval.

- Bill
- Bill.Products
- Bill.Surcharges
- Bill.Products.Surcharges

However, swapping the lines declaring Products and Surcharges results in the following sequence.

- Bill
- Bill.Surcharges
- Bill.Products
- Bill.Products.Surcharges

On the contrary, interchanging Include() does not seem to have any consequences. I use EF 5.

In order to avoid an over-complicated event handling (responsible for property value updates in all entity objects of a given bill tree, I am looking for certain assumptions.

Is it, in your opinion, reasonable to assume that a certain load sequence is kept?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191288/how-to-determine-the-order-of-property-loading-in-codefirst

Answer (score 0):

After assuming that at least the parent entity is loaded before the child (i.e. Bill is loaded before Product), I was enlightened today (thanks to Colin Blair!), as a child entity was loaded before the parent. So, for initializing event handling, there are the following two solutions.

1. Overriding OnLoaded and consider that child entities might already exist in the entity collections (i.e. Bill.Prodcuts.Count != 0)
2. Asynchronously invocation of the initialization code (which is executed after the complete entity tree is loaded), as described by Colin Blair. [1]

[1] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/7c2802b2-7a7e-4655-aba6-900b6e9ef626/observing-loading-child-entities-by-adding-event-handlers-in-an-overriden-onloaded-method